# Find best combination of array items taking a bunch of margin considerations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, recursion

I have an array of items I want to find the best combination of, to match a target with margins both on the items and the target.

I have attempted a bunch of recursion functions, but the margin thing gets me all confused!

I have a set of tables – yes, real wooden tables ;) – stacked up to a combined length, and a number of tablecloths of varying length; array(130, 180, 240)

The cloths should extend each side of the table by at least 20cm, and no more than 40cm, and each cloth should overlap its neighbor by a minimum of 5cm.

SO, if the total table length is 540cm, the target length is 580 to 620cm, and the ideal combination would be 240x2, 130x1. Other combinations such as 130x5 are not ideal as more items will not look as good.

Then we also have to take into consideration than the table length could be only 180cm where a single 240cm, cloth item would be enough.

Should run in web browser (with jQuery included), or alternatively I can set up a PHP script with ajax if PHP is better suited for this.

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment. At a minimum you should post what you have written. Recursion is a reasonable way to handle it. Generally speaking, you have a target length, 540 which is really 580 and up to 620. You would 'apply' your widest cloth- 240, `240 < 580` clearly, so you now need `(580-240) = 340`, actually 345 to allow for the 5 cm overlap.  You could then repeat this cycle. You'd also have the logic for looking at the next smaller-sized cloth if the larger one would push you over the upper bound limit. (which would also effectively grow by 5 cm for each cloth.

Comment: Yes, @barry-johnson it does sound like a school example, but its real world ;) I have a working solution [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u5uh/) but it is not very neat. And the prior question (not stated before) how to find the right combination of tables for n people, got me thinking that the fit as many largest, then next largest approach is not optimal. For instance if you have tables for 6 and 4 people, and want to seat 20 people - the best match is 2+2, not 3+1. Which got me into bitmasks - but I havent got that one figured out yet!